# Which fontsize does "em" refer to in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, textwidth

With `tikz`, I set font size to `\footnotesize`, but `text width=5em` is not as wide as 5 times width of one character from `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,text width=5em] {\lipsum[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

And this one  `text width=5\widthof{\footnotesize X}` will cause error. What is the reason and how should I repair it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "5 times \footnotesize"?

Comment: A better title for the question is problably: "Which fontsize does `em` refer to in Tikz?" As I do not think it is dynamically adjusted.

Comment: @lukeflo 5em whenever `\footnotesize` is in effect (ignoring that `em` is not really the font size)

Comment: @daleif  Yes, I changed the title.

Comment: @daleif 5em with fontsize `footnotesize` would make sense since its a length. But the OP states "5 times \footnotesize" which might be a typo but makes no real sense.

Comment: @lukeflo  As wide as 5 times the width of one character of `\footnotesize`.

Comment: @Y.zeng OK that's more clear. But `em` refers not to any character but in most cases width of an uppercase `M`.

Comment: +1 for the clarification in the title. That indeed could be a question other users might have too.

Comment: @lukeflo Fot what size? `\footnote size` or the default?  How can I set it to 5 times the width of one character of `\footnotesize`?

Comment: `em` isn't a fixed width. Normally it changes with fontsize. Thus, `1em` in `footnotesize` is a different dimen than in `Large`. That's why your question might be interesting. To which set fontsize does `em` refer in `tikz`. (I don't know either without checking, sorry)

Comment: @Y.zeng, did you try entering "MMMMM "? Regardless of "em", ... what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MS-SPO  This one, `text width={MMMMMM}` , not work

Comment: like most assignments, `text width` has to take a value that _expands_ to a length, not a block of code that does other assignments. You can not do `\textwidth=\sbox0{abc}\wd0`  you have to do `\sbox0{abc}\textwidth=\wd0` so the thing on the right hand side is (or expands to) a length.

Comment: @lukeflo although the name em comes from M, in most fonts M is not exactly 1em wide.  The em size is just an arbitrary length set in the font metrics by the font designer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK thanks for the clarification. In most manuals it states that `em` is roughly the width of an uppercase M (of course not exactly, should've made that clearer).

Comment: `font` only sets the font inside the text of a node, all measurements are still done in the font size that's active outside of it. Use `node font = \footnotesize` instead if you want `ex` and `em` to relate to the footnote size in regards to all node measurements, then you can simply use `text width=5*width("X")`. Using `text width = 5*width("\footnotesize X")` will fail in many cases inside a TikZ picture because of the way it handles fonts inside it. You can however to `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\myWidth{5*width("\footnotesize X")}` outside TikZ and use `text width=\myWidth` inside.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle May you made this clearer, `\textwidth=\sbox0{abc}\wd0` not work but `\sbox0{abc}\textwidth=\wd0` works and what should I do after `\sbox0{abc}\textwidth=\wd0`?

Comment: @Y.zeng I didn't mean you should use that here, it's just another example of the same problem (without all the tikz) once you start assigning a length such as `\textwidth=`  (or `\setlength{\textwidth}{....}` the value has to _expand_ to a length, you can not do some arbitrary nested calculations and assignments and then produce a length.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Ti*k*Z first switches to the current font (as valid outside the picture) and computes the 5em; only later it does `\footnoteseize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\ttt{aa bb cc d ee f gg h ii jj kk l m nn o p q r ss tt uu}

\begin{document}

\noindent{\footnotesize\kern-0.4pt\vrule\strut\hspace{5em}\vrule}

\noindent\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.4pt\kern-0.4pt\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0pt]
    \node[rectangle,text width=5em] {\ttt};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\noindent{\kern-0.4pt\vrule\strut\hspace{5em}\vrule}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's immaterial if you have `\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}` outside the picture.

On the other hand, if you set `\footnotesize` inside the picture…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\ttt{aa bb cc d ee f gg h ii jj kk l m nn o p q r ss tt uu}

\begin{document}

\noindent{\footnotesize\kern-0.4pt\vrule\strut\hspace{5em}\vrule}

\noindent\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.4pt\kern-0.4pt\fbox{%
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
\footnotesize
    \node[rectangle,text width=5em] {\ttt};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\noindent{\kern-0.4pt\vrule\strut\hspace{5em}\vrule}

\end{document}
```

[image]